# Functions $f$ whose series differs depending on the order of expansion

Tags: functions, taylor-expansion

Consider the following function:
$$
F(x,y) \ = \ \frac{x^2y}{x^4+y^2}
$$

Expanding $x=0$ and $y=0$, it is a cool example of a function whose series  depends on the order in which you take the expansion:
$$
\mathrm{about\ }x=0 \mathrm{\ first}\ \ \ \implies F(x,y) \approx\frac{x^2}{y} \\
\mathrm{about\ }y=0 \mathrm{\ first}\ \ \ \implies F(x,y) \approx\frac{y}{x^2}
$$

There is clearly a very bad singularity at $(x,y) = (0,0)$ for this particular function.

My question is:

Does there exist a function $f(x,y)$ which for an expansion about some point $(x_0,y_0)$, there is a different series depending on the order in which you expand the variables **where $f(x_0,y_0)$ is constant and not singular**?

I am imagining if there is such a function, then the funny point $(x_0,y_0)$ would be a saddle point or something of that nature.

Comment: As far as I know, Taylor expansion in $\;n\;$ variables is done about a point $\;\overline x=(x_1,...,x_n)\in\Bbb R^n\;$ , **not** about "this value for $\;x_2\;$ and then about that value for $\;x_1\;$ and etc."

Comment: This function is not even continuous at $(0,0)$ and cannot be made continuous.

Comment: There is something similar to what you are doing, but you need to consider this function as a rational function on projective plane. The homogeneization of this function would be $z^4f(x/z,y/z)=\frac{x^2yz}{x^4+y^2z^2}$, then the expansion at different points that lie outside the chart $z\neq0$ will look similar to that. For example, the first one would start with the term $\frac{x^2}{yz}+...$ The different series are at different points. But in this way you can make sense of asymptotics that look like those and the identity principle of powers series remains unharmed.

Answer (score 0):

If I read this correctly, what you ask for is not a full expansion (Taylor) but the behavior of the function at $x=x_0$ and  at $y=y_0$.

Consider

$$
F(x,y) = (1+x)(1+y)^2
$$
near $(x_0,y_0) = (0,0)$.

With your approach, at $x=0$ you have $(1+y)^2$, at  $y=0$ you have $(1+x)$.

So this is different, however only at first sight. Because what this really shows is the behavior of $F(x,y)$ on the $y$-axis (for  $x=0$) and on the $x$-axis (for  $y=0$).

However, near $(x_0,y_0) = (0,0)$ the correct Taylor expansion to first order is $1 + x + 2y$  and this does not depend on the order of approximation. Multivariable Taylor expansion is guaranteed to work (which entails independence of any order of operations) if  $F(x,y)$ and all (mixed in variables) partial derivatives are bounded and continuous at $(x_0,y_0)$.

Comment: This is not correct.  The function is not even continuous at $(0,0)$.  Note if we approach along $x=0$ or along $y=0$, then the limit is obviously $0$.  If we approach along $y=x^2$, then the limit is $1/2$.